# Send ajax success response to jQuery Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

How to send ajax success response to jQuery Modal ([jQuery Modal Site](http://kylefox.ca/jquery-modal/examples/)) when i click submit and automatically show modal with response. This is my ajax to post:

```
$('#rincian').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        data: $(this).serializeArray(),
        type: $(this).attr('method'), 
        url: $(this).attr('action'), 
        success: function(response) { 
            $('#rinci').html(response); 
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
```

**UPDATE**
Answered by [Jossef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3191896/jossef-harush)

I have changed it to `$('#rinci').html(response).modal();`

```
$('#rincian').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serializeArray(),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'), 
        success: function(response) {
            $('#rinci').html(response).modal();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: have you tried to add $('#rinci').html(response).modal() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/5WEVL/

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '', 
        success: function(response) { 
            $('#modal-div').html(response).modal();
        }
    }); 
});
```

add `.modal();` and it should work